# Ajax call not working until page refresh

Tags: ajax, routes

When I just logged in this ajax request not working. When I hit refresh (F5) in my browser, then works well on all pages, and see in firebug call to `/js/my-callback/`. History repeats if I logout, login... What I should add to this function to work properly?

```
(function ($) {

  Drupal.behaviors.myModule = {
     attach: function(context, settings) {
       $.ajax({
         url: '/js/my-callback/',
         success: function(data) {
            $('#myID', context).html(data);
         }
       });
     }
  };

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: Hi Aboodred1. I just want to add user specific content to page (flags etc.), but not attached full code here, because its all works well, but only when I refresh the page. I dont know why its happend, every time I must refresh browser to get ajax call.

Comment: because you are firing the ajax callback on page load.

Comment: Yes, I want it on every page, so if I just login, there is no page load or what?

Comment: So you want it to run on every page whether you're logged in or not?

Comment: Yes, and its works whether I'm logged in or not, but only after F5 (page refresh in browser), I hit F5 when logged, and until I logout all works well on all pages. When I logout, not working until I hit again F5 :(

Comment: how do you logout? are you just clicking on the logout link?

Comment: Another thing, are you caching drupal for anonymous users?

Comment: Yes, just normally, it's drupal 7.22 default install without any additional modules. edit: not cache enabled for anonymous.

Comment: hmm, are you trying to ajax your entire site? When you log out from Drupal to which page Drupal is redirecting you to?

Comment: Thanks for your help @Aboodred1. After logout Drupal redirecting to fornt page (default). What I'm trying to do is simply I want cache pages with varnish, and display only user specific content with ajax call, but its doesn't matter now, because I'm not behind varnish, installed default Drupal to check what's wrong. All work inside Drupal.bechaviors.myModule eg. alert('some text') work when logout-login, but not ajax call until I refresh page, very strange:(

Comment: I tried your javascript code; it worked for me, but I replaced the url with an absolute url. You might have something else effecting your code - caching or javascript error.

Comment: It looks like something with cache related. I make php file in root folder, then all works perfectly `/my-custom-file.php/`, later I changed in hook_menu() 'page callback' to 'delivery callback' and its works also. Don't know it is safe or something, don't know is any code in hook_menu is for cache setup, but for now its working :) Thank You @Aboodred1 for your time and good clue. Thank's ;)